# Как в matplotlib построить график неявной функции?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Дана кривая, заданная неявно: x^2/3 + y^2/3 = 8
Как построить её график, используя matplotlib?

Comment: связанный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/q/2484527/4279

Comment: @Suvitruf к чему полезный вопрос закрывать? Посмотрите на его аналог на большом SO: +18 рейтинг, +5 в избранном, более 16 тысяч просмотров, 6 ответов, последний из которых (аналогичный моему ответу) был опубликован через 2 года после публикации вопроса. Посетителей из гугла   с похожей проблемой интересует решения, а не попытки автора. Зачем препятствовать публикации лучшего решения в будущем? [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044)

Comment: @jfs спасибо, переоткрыли.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно [`sympy.plot_implicit()`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html#sympy.plotting.plot_implicit.plot_implicit) использовать (по умолчанию с помощью matplotlib рисует):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> var('x y')
(x, y)
>>> plot_implicit(Eq(x**2/3+y**2/3, 8))
```

[image: plot x**2/3+y**2/3=8]