# Как рисовать 3D объекты, заданные _неявной_ функцией типа z^2-x^2-y^2=0

Tags: python, python-3.x, графика, matplotlib

Нужно нарисовать объект `z^2-x^2-y^2=0`. Это два конуса вершинами в точке 0.
Если данный объект я еще могу нарисовать использовав две функции, выразив при этом z (`z=sqrt(x^2+y^2); z=-sqrt(x^2+y^2)`), то в дальнейшем мне нужно будет рисовать более сложные объекты, где это невозможно. Для двухмерного обьекта есть такое решение:

```
y, x = np.ogrid[-5:5:100j, -5:5:100j]
plt.contour(x.ravel(), y.ravel(), pow(y, 2) - pow(x, 2), [0])
```

Можно ли это решение применить для трехмерного или существует какое-то другое?

Мой код:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

X = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.01)
Y = np.arange(-2, 2, 0.01)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y) 
R = X**2+Y**2
Z1 = np.sqrt(R)
Z2 = -np.sqrt(R)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z2)

plt.show()
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как в matplotlib построить график неявной функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/741048/23044)

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь [решением от @Paul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4687582/5741205):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def plot_implicit(fn, bbox=(-2.5,2.5)):
    ''' create a plot of an implicit function
    fn  ...implicit function (plot where fn==0)
    bbox ..the x,y,and z limits of plotted interval'''
    xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, zmin, zmax = bbox*3
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    A = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 100) # resolution of the contour
    B = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 15) # number of slices
    A1,A2 = np.meshgrid(A,A) # grid on which the contour is plotted

    for z in B: # plot contours in the XY plane
        X,Y = A1,A2
        Z = fn(X,Y,z)
        cset = ax.contour(X, Y, Z+z, [z], zdir='z')
        # [z] defines the only level to plot for this contour for this value of z

    for y in B: # plot contours in the XZ plane
        X,Z = A1,A2
        Y = fn(X,y,Z)
        cset = ax.contour(X, Y+y, Z, [y], zdir='y')

    for x in B: # plot contours in the YZ plane
        Y,Z = A1,A2
        X = fn(x,Y,Z)
        cset = ax.contour(X+x, Y, Z, [x], zdir='x')

    # must set plot limits because the contour will likely extend
    # way beyond the displayed level.  Otherwise matplotlib extends the plot limits
    # to encompass all values in the contour.
    ax.set_zlim3d(zmin,zmax)
    ax.set_xlim3d(xmin,xmax)
    ax.set_ylim3d(ymin,ymax)

    plt.show()

def f1(x,y,z):
    return z**2-x**2-y**2

plot_implicit(f1)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно [`mayavi` использовать для 3D графиков](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html#d-plotting-functions-for-numpy-arrays). К примеру, чтобы конус нарисовать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np       
from mayavi import mlab  

x, y, z = np.mgrid[-2:2:100j, -2:2:100j, -2:2:100j]
mlab.figure()
mlab.contour3d(x, y, z, z**2-x**2-y**2, contours=[0])
mlab.axes()
mlab.show()
```

[image: cone]

Для установки на Питон 3 нужны версии Питон пакетов с репозитория: pyface, traitsui, mayavi.